# Launch web driver without instaling it?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I was trying to launch a `PhantomJS` browser and it works on Azure VM.
(I just point the PhantomJS.exe and it works)

Then I try to launch a `google web-driver` and its asking me to locate the google installed location. (I dont install google chrome browser).

So is there any other web drivers like `PhantomJS` which I dont need to install in order to launch it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [HTMLUnit](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver) and [Rhino+Env.JS](http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2011/09/rhino-and-envjs/). But just like Phantom.JS I do not think they are actively developed. Suggested is to install Firefox or Chrome and use their headless mode.

You could also try https://www.cypress.io/ which ships with Chromium and Electron.

Comment: Cool ,Thanks @Niels.

Comment: Hi @Niels I tryed HtmlUnitDriver on my .net project seems to be its not supporting .Net.And i tryed IE  headless mode and it says unable to start the process.Becouse im trying to do some tricky thing which is runing a selenium script as a app-service on Azure. So i dont have access to the actual VM its hosting And thats why i cant install apps firefox or chrome browsers on it.

Comment: I dont think you should try to use HtmlUnitDriver unless your application was built TDD against it. IE does not have a headless modes. Get access, or change your test infrastructure so you do control it. I think running Selenium tests as a app-service is a whole new question on its own. Which I do not have an answer for. Why dont you use hosted WebDriver service and let it run tests against your Azure application?

Comment: hosted WebDriver service ... mmmm.This is somthing new to me.Let me try.

Comment: yeah saucelabs or testingbot, but research more newer services :)